# Spectrum of self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space real

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

My book says that a self-adjoint bounded linear operator $A:H\to H$ on a complex Hilbert (not sure if separability is needed) space has a real spectrum.

I guess that the key is in the fact that any $f\in H^{\ast}$ can be represented by a functional of the form $\langle-,x_0\rangle$ for some $x_0\in H$, but I am not able to use that fact. I also see that $\forall x,y\in H\quad\langle(A-\lambda I)x,y\rangle=\langle x,(A-\bar{\lambda} I)y\rangle$ but I'm not sure that can be useful to prove the statement...

Thank you very much for any help!!!

Comment: I think you forgot to write self-adjoint in your first sentence, even though you write self-adjoint in the title.

Comment: Thank you so much: yes, I did. Edited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $\Im\lambda \ne 0$, and $x \in X$, then
$$
        \Im\lambda \|x\|^{2} = -\Im((A-\lambda I)x,x),\\
          |\Im\lambda|\|x\|^{2} \le |((A-\lambda I)x,x)|\le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|\|x\|,\\
                |\Im\lambda|\|x\| \le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|.
$$
So $A-\lambda I$ is injective for all $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$. The above inequality can be used to show that the range $\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)$ is closed for $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$. So $A-\lambda I$ is surjective for $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$ because
$$
\begin{align}
      \mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)& =\overline{\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)} \\
         & =\mathcal{N}(A^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)^{\perp} \\
         & = \mathcal{N}(A-\overline{\lambda}I)^{\perp}=\{0\}^{\perp}=H.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $A-\lambda I$ is injective and surjective for $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$, which leaves $\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! My text proposes lemmas to be proven as exercises of a level often much higher than the preparation given in theory part, so I have found material on line to understand why $\overline{\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)}=\mathcal{N}(A^{\ast}-\bar{\lambda}I)^{\perp}$, but I still don't understand how to realise that such a range is closed. Moreover why $\Im\lambda\|x\|^{2}=\Im((A-\lambda I)x,x)$ (I only see that $((A-\lambda I)x,x)=(Ax,x)-\lambda\|x\|^2$) and why $\mathcal{N}(A^{\ast}-\bar{\lambda}I)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(A-\bar{\lambda}I)^{\perp}$? $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: @DavideZena : $A^{\star}=A$ which is why $\mathcal{N}(A^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)=\mathcal{N}(A-\overline{\lambda}I)$. Because $A=A^{\star}$, you also know that $(Ax,x)$ is real because $(Ax,x)^{\star}=(x,Ax)=(A^{\star}x,x)=(Ax,x)$. Finally, the inequality shows the range is closed because $(A-\lambda I)x_{n}\rightarrow y$ implies $\Im\lambda\|x_{n}-x_{m}\| \le \|(A-\lambda I)(x_{n}-x_{m})\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n,m\rightarrow \infty$; that then gives $\lim_{n}x_{n}=x$ for some $x$ and, so, $(A-\lambda I)x_{n}\rightarrow (A-\lambda)x$ which gives $y=(A-\lambda I)x$ is in the range.

Comment: As to not seeing that $A^{\ast}=A$, I'm quite embarassed :-s. $\aleph_1$ thanks!

Comment: @DavideZena : You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: That $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is continuous for $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$ seems to be considered obvious. Is this because of the open mapping theorem or for more elementary reasons?

Comment: @Stefan : I just noticed your comment. It's because of the inequality $|\Im\lambda| \|x\| \le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|$ that the inverse is bounded on its domain for $\Im\lambda \ne 0$. And that domain is dense to begin with, which makes it extend continuously to the full space.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded?

Comment: @Balai_Indah : $|\Im\lambda|\|x\|\le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|$ implies $\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}y\|\le \frac{1}{|\Im\lambda|}\|y\|$ for all $y$ in the range of $A-\lambda I$, which is a dense subspace. So the inverse has a unique continuous extension.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the spectrum of $A$ is real when $A = A^*$ is a general fact about commutative $C^*$ algebras; the discussion of $A$ as an operator on Hilbert space is not needed.  The main point is that in such a $C^*$ algebra, we have $||xx^*|| = ||x||^2$ for all $x$, and the spectral radius $\rho(x) = ||x||$ for all $x$.  Thus if $Y$ is a large real number (large multiple of the identity), then $$\rho(A+iY)^2 = ||A+iY||^2 = ||A^2+Y^2|| = Y^2 + O(1).$$  Now if $x+iy$ is in the spectrum of $A$, say with $y>0$, then $\rho(A+iY)^2 > |x+iy+iY|^2 > (y+Y)^2$ and hence $y=0$.  Thus the spectrum of $A$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

The representation of the elements of $H^*$ is not needed.

Let $\lambda$ be in the point spectrum of $A$. Then there is $0\neq x\in H=(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ and by the self-adjointness of $A$:
$\lambda(x,x)=(\lambda x,x)=(Ax,x)=(x,Ax)=(x,\lambda x)=\overline{\lambda}(x,x)$.
Hence $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$, thus $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem for related results in greater generality.

Comment: Forgive me if I don't understand: why $A-\lambda I=0$? I only know that, if $\lambda$ is in the (continuous or punctual) spectrum, $A-\lambda I$ isn't bijective... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I've edited the answer, but the case where $\lambda\in\sigma\setminus\sigma_p$ still needs to be done.

Comment: No problem: thank you again!