# Range of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a self adjoint operator in a Hilbert space $H$. Let $I$ be the identity operator on $H$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}$. Why does it hold that the range of $$T-izI$$  is $H$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is only true if $z\ne0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $\sigma(T) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925097/144766).

Now $iz \notin \mathbb{R}$ so $T-izI$ is invertible. In particular, $T-izI$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much!