# Is this a characterization of the resolvent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am trying to understand a statement that is in some notes that I am reading right now. It is the following.

"Let $T$ be a bounded, self-adjoint operator, $\eta\in\mathbb{R}, \eta\neq 0$ and let $H$ be an Hilbert space. It can easily proved that $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is bounded from $H$ to itself. Hence it is the resolvent of $T$."

I don't understand why the boundeness of $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ implies that it is the resolvent of $T$. It is a sort of characterization?

I searched something on the web, but I didn't find anything. Could anyone please help? Also some references will be well accepted.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $T$ self-adjoint?

Comment: I suppose the operator is linear and $i$ is the identity, right?

Comment: @cmk yes, it is also self-adjoint, i missed while writing.

Comment: @G. Chiusole the operator is linear and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is bounded and self-adjoint, then $\sigma(T)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ (see [Spectrum of self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925097/spectrum-of-self-adjoint-operator-on-hilbert-space-real)). However, the spectrum is defined as a subset of $\mathbb{C}.$ Taking complements, you get that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}\subseteq \rho(T).$ That is, if $\eta\in\mathbb{R},$ then $i\eta\in\rho(T).$ Thus, the resolvent $R_\eta:=(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is defined, and it is bounded by e.g. the bounded inverse theorem.

If $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ exists, then it means that $i\eta$ is in the resolvent set of $T$, and $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is called the resolvent of $T$. It is the *definition* of the resolvent.

Comment: So, I just wanted to know "if $T$ is a self-adjoint, linear, bounded operator and $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is bounded, then $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is necessarely the resolvent of $T$?" Are you saying that it is true?

Comment: If $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ exists, then it means that $i\eta$ is in the resolvent set of $T$, and $(T-i\eta)^{-1}$ is called the resolvent of $T$. It's the definition. I'll edit this in.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patience

Comment: Sorry, just for curiosity. If $T$ is not self-adjoint, could you say something similar or not?

Comment: @C.Bishop Not necessarily. You need to know that $i\eta$ is in the resolvent set. There are plenty of operators that have spectrum which intersect the imaginary axis, but this is impossible for a self adjoint operator.

Comment: So your answer does not work also for non self-adjoint operators, isn't it?

Comment: That's correct. The last part makes sense in general. However, if the operator is not self-adjoint, it's possible that $i\eta$ is not in the resolvent set, in which case the resolvent (at $\eta$) is not defined.